# Git diff branch - filter by extension?

Tags: git

I'm diffing 2 branches with `git diff master..branch2` and diff shows me html, css, php files, etc. I'd like to only view php files here, but `git diff master..branch2 -- '*.php'` returns nothing. How do I actually filter it?

Comment: `git diff master..branch2 -- '*.php'` works for me. Maybe you need `git diff master..branch2 -- '**/*.php'` to search in subdirectories? Or maybe there weren't any changes.

Comment: @DanielGibbs, yes, that worked ok in a test repo, but not in the main one. There were definitely a lot of changes `git diff master..branch2 | grep "diff.*.php" | wc -l` shows 203. But `**/*.php` did not work still to show these files.

Comment: I guess that has to do with version - it works fine in `1.9.1`, but not in `1.7.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this was an issue with the version of git - Centos 6.5 has 1.7.1 in current yum. I've updated it to 1.9.4 manually and it all worked!